# How to properly handle an aborted HTTP request in Django

Tags: django

Whenever a lengthy HTTP requests is aborted by the client (e.g. Browser is closed) Django views seem to raise a IOError exception.

What's the proper way to detect such an aborted request if I just want to ignore them? Just catching IOError seems too wide.. might accidentally ignore other IO problems.

Answer (score 2):

In django 1.3 and up, you can use a [logging filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-filters) class to suppress the exceptions which you aren't interested in. Here's the logging filter class I'm using to narrowly suppress IOError exceptions raised from `_get_raw_post_data()`:

```
import sys, traceback
class _SuppressUnreadablePost(object):
    def filter(self, record):
        _, exception, tb = sys.exc_info()
        if isinstance(exception, IOError):
            for _, _, function, _ in traceback.extract_tb(tb):
                if function == '_get_raw_post_data':
                    return False
        return True
```

In Django 1.4, you will be able to do away with most of the complexity and suppress the new exception class `UnreadablePostError`. (See [this patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17493)).

Comment: Do I need to call this function inside my main function, if yes what parameter are required to be passed in this function?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it would be to use a custom middleware class that implements [`process_exception()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process-exception) to return a custom HTTP response, say a rendered `errors/request_aborted.html` template, if an `IOException` is caught.

Comment: But what if some other IOError is thrown, not as a result of aborting but for some other reason? I would then suppress that error...

Comment: This works for uncaught exceptions. You'll generally try to catch all the possible exceptions when your doing IO to make sure that only aborted requests are uncaught.

Comment: But it's not that easy to tell where an IOError can come from. E.g. I see it often being raised just by accessing request.POST. I need a way of telling apart client disconnection from every other type of IO error, while assuming that an IOError can be raised by almost any framework function.

Comment: If you really want to be precise about it, your middleware can catch the exception and evaluate the exception message.

Comment: The exception message doesn't seem like it contains anything that would identify exception as a connection-terminated exception. I also think it's brittle, because the message itself may change slightly between machines (e.g. depending on the directories where django/python files are located).

Comment: Note that middleware process_exception() is also limited to processing exceptions that originated in view code; if the exception originates in another middleware, process_exception() is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Raven now connects itself to the [got_request_exception()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#got-request-exception) signal to catch unhandled exceptions, bypassing the logging system entirely, so the solution proposed by dlowe does not work anymore.

However raven looks for a `skip_sentry` attribute on the exception instance, so you can use a middleware to set it on the errors you want to ignore:

```
import sys
import traceback


class FilterPostErrorsMiddleware(object):
    """
    A middleware that prevents unreadable POST errors to reach Sentry.
    """

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if isinstance(exception, IOError):
            tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
            for _, _, function, _ in traceback.extract_tb(tb):
                if function == '_get_raw_post_data':
                    exception.skip_sentry = True
                    break
```

**Note**: you have to use a recent version of raven (e.g. 1.8.4), as previous versions mistakenly checked for the `skip_sentry` attribute on the exception type rather than instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the `IOError`, then just let it be.  You don't need to catch it.  If you absolutely must catch it, you can do what @Filip Dupanović suggested, and maybe return a `django.http.HttpResponseServerError` to set the response code to `500`.

Comment: I don't want to let it be because I log all uncaught errors, and this produces log noise.